# implement action bar on android API 7

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

I am working on **Android 2.1** with **API v7**.

How can I implement the action bar in this old version API which can work like built-in ActionBar on devices supporting **API 11** or greater? Is there any support package ?

(A good tutorial on how to implement action bar in old version API is appreciated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can/should use [this](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) ActionBar project. 
It's very very simple to use and I am using it myself in one project.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an examle of adding actionBar with slides menu to api>7:

https://github.com/BradleyRL/NavDrawerExampleAppCompat-v7

It's documented here for api>14 http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html. (first link - is upgraded method of second link to support previous versions).

Then, you could read documentation here: developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

To do this this way you must add project library to your project (and  for exammple in 1t link too).
To do it: File>New>Other>Android Project From Existing Code>Browse (Select "YOUR_PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat"), check adding it to workspace>Finish.

Then go to properties of your(example in 1st link) project>android>add (choose this library)>OK.
And you must extend your main class from ActionBarActivity insted of Activity. I try this, and it work on 2.3.7 and on 4.1.1 versions)

Hope it helps)

P.S. Sorry for my bad english and hi from Russia)